# Alternative ways to code something like a table within a table?

Tags: tables

I need to do diagrams like this for homework.

[image]

Presumably I could do this by putting tables inside tables, but that seems really tedious.

Is there any way to achieve such an effect with shorter, cleaner code?

Comment: Please show us a compilable minimal example.

Comment: @Niranjan - I'm looking for advice on approaches, not help fixing a specific instance.

Comment: Your title says "alternative ways", but you have shown no approach for which you need an alternative. Just mentioning it in words really doesn't give us any idea. You might not even need a table inside a table. The diagram that you show can be a single table too, but without writing some actual code one can't predict which one will be shorter and cleaner amongst the two approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a matrix with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        column sep=2mm,
        row sep={-\pgflinewidth},
        nodes={
            draw, 
            fill=blue!20,
            text width=1.25ex,
            text height=1.5ex,
            text depth=0pt,
            align=center,
            anchor=center,
        },
        row 1/.style={
            row sep=2mm,
            nodes={
                draw=none,
                fill=none,
            }
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[mymatrix] {
    7  & 0  & 1  & 2  & 0  & 3  \\
    7  & 7  & 7  & 2  &    & 2  \\
    {} & 0  & 0  & 0  &    & 3  \\
    {} & {} & 1  & 1  &    & 1  \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you have an assignment where you'll need to typeset arbitrary diagrams that resemble tables, then it'd be ideal to automate the process with a few macros.

**Code**

Below, the `\createCol` macro accepts four inputs, and creates a column with blue cells. If you want a column that only has a number at the top but no blue cells, you `\noBlueCol` is a macro that accepts a single input. LaTeX treats tables as though they're text (well, sort of—the tables get put into *boxes* and are inserted in line with rows of text), and because each table has the same vertical size, they'll all end up aligned in rows so long as you don't break paragraphs.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\createCol}[4]{\begin{tabular}{c}
#1
\\
{}
\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightBlue}#2}
\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightBlue}#3}
\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor{LightBlue}#4}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\noBlueCol}[1]{\begin{tabular}{c}
#1
\\
{}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\phantom{1}}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
\\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\createCol{1}{2}{3}{4}
\createCol{1}{2}{}{}
\createCol{2}{4}{6}{}
\noBlueCol{2}
\createCol{3}{4}{5}{6}
\createCol{3}{2}{1}{0}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output of the TeX program showing colored tables]

Answer (score 3):

With square cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\mystrut}{%
  \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr0.5\dp\strutbox+\fontcharht\font`0}%
  \rule[-0.5\dp\strutbox]{0pt}{0.5\dp\strutbox}%
}

\newcommand{\stack}[4]{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|>{\cellcolor{LightBlue}\mystrut}wc{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\fontcharht\font`0}|}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}\\[1ex]
  \hline
  #2 \\ \hline
  #3 \\ \hline
  #4 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\nostack}[1]{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\fontcharht\font`0+2\arrayrulewidth]{#1}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \stack{7}{7}{}{}\hfill
  \stack{0}{7}{0}{}\hfill
  \stack{1}{7}{0}{1}\hfill
  \stack{2}{2}{0}{1}\hfill
  \nostack{0}\hfill
  \stack{3}{2}{3}{1}\hfill
  \stack{0}{2}{3}{0}\hfill
  \stack{4}{4}{3}{0}\hfill
  \stack{2}{4}{2}{0}\hfill
  \stack{3}{4}{2}{3}\hfill
  \stack{0}{0}{2}{3}\hfill
  \nostack{3}\hfill
  \nostack{2}\hfill
  \stack{1}{0}{1}{3}\hfill
  \stack{2}{0}{1}{2}\hfill
  \nostack{0}\hfill
  \nostack{1}\hfill
  \stack{7}{7}{1}{2}\hfill
  \stack{0}{7}{0}{2}\hfill
  \stack{1}{7}{0}{1}
\end{center}

\bigskip

\noindent
\mbox{\small
  \stack{7}{7}{}{}\enspace
  \stack{0}{7}{0}{}\enspace
  \stack{1}{7}{0}{1}\enspace
  \stack{2}{2}{0}{1}\enspace
  \nostack{0}\enspace
  \stack{3}{2}{3}{1}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]